# Negation of zero produces false

Tags: javascript, boolean, zero

I got an issue that negation of zero produces *false* in my JavaScript code.
I have simplified the code to demo the issue as given below.

```
<input id="iid" value="0" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  zero = document.getElementById('iid').value;  
  alert( ( !zero ? 'true' : 'false' ) );  // alert message is "false".
</script>
```

Why negation of zero become *false*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're negating the string `"0"`. Any string becomes `false` when negated except the empty string:

```
!0       true
!"0"     false
!""      true
!+"0"    true
```

The last expression is `true` because the `+` operator converts the string into a number.

An input value is always a string, which makes sense semantically as well because it's a combination of characters entered by the user. If you want to interpret is as a number you'll have to convert it into one yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The string `"0"` is "`true`", negating it is `false`.

If you want a number, you should parse it:

```
var valueAsNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('iid').value, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because that's not the *number* zero, it's a *string* with the character "0" in it.  All non-empty strings, regardless of what characters are in them, are `true` when treated as booleans.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
<input id="iid" value="0" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  zero = Number(document.getElementById('iid').value);  
  alert( ( !zero ? 'true' : 'false' ) );
</script>
```